# How do I export a MIDI to a sound file without playing it in realtime?

Tags: export, midi

Many people out there say that the easiest way to export MIDI to a sound file is by playing back the MIDI file in question and recording it with Stereo Mix.

However, I have many MIDI files I would like to export and this process could easily take a very long time. I am also using a custom MIDI synth. I was thinking that I could use ffmpeg, but I am not sure how well supported MIDI exporting is.

How can I export MIDI without having to play it back in realtime and record it with Stereo Mix?

Comment: What MIDI synth?

Comment: @CL. CoolSoft VirtualMIDISynth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the right tools, the process is extremely simple:

1. [Download](http://www.synthfont.com/WinampPluginSetup.exe) the Winamp plugin for SynFon. It's free, and, unlike the Nullsoft MIDI input, in_aSynFon can be passed to an output plug-in.
2. Configure the plugin (it asks you for a SoundFont) and set Nullsoft Disk Writer as the main output plug-in.
3. Open the MIDI file.
4. The song should export to disk in only a few seconds.

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few programs that can do this. There's SynthFont - the old version is a free download. If you have a soundfont, you could also use Spesoft Audio Converter (I personally recommend this one because the output is good quality)

You'll need a soundfont as an sf2 file. If you don't have one, you could try FluidR3. http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fluid-soundfont/fluid-soundfont_3.1.orig.tar.gz